# C# REST API Service access to path denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I'm very new to Windows environment, I've struggle a lot making my c# API work on IIS. I only managed to do a GET on my Web API.

When I try to do a POST, I get this:

```
{"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Access to the path 'C:\\Path\\To\\API' is denied.",
"ExceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at MiningAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Post(HttpRequestMessage request) in C:\\Users\\Tavernier\\Desktop\\MiningReport\\MiningAPI\\MiningAPI\\Controllers\\ValuesController.cs:line 90\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Permissions on `IUSRS` and `IIS_IUSRS` are fully allowed to read files on the Web API folder.
I'm on Windows 10, running IIS-10

**UPDATE:**

POST was working when I launched the Web API through Visual Studio. (localhost:port, now 192.168.1.30:port)

I tried to move my folder to `D:`, added `NETWORK SERVICE` to the permissions.

Comment: [How to configure Web server permissions for Web content in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313075/how-to-configure-web-server-permissions-for-web-content-in-iis)

Comment: What are you doing inside your `Post` method? Seems like you're trying to manipulate a file, and the application pool identity doesn't have the rights to do so.

Comment: @Liam did you notice those instructions are for IIS 5?

Comment: My 'POST' is taking arguments in the `Body` then generate a file depending of this arguments and sends back a web address. (http://192.168.1.30/user/chart.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user being used depends on your application pool.  If no identity has been specific within the IIS Application Pool used by your application, then the default will be "IIS AppPool\<AppPool Name>" (without quotes).

see https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities for more information.

I would recommend that any folders the app pool user needs to write to, is granted permission to explicitly.  It would be unwise to allow the app pool user full write access especially to code directories, as that could lead to modification of sources if present.

#### Code to check permissions

Here is some code that will do a basic check for permissions.  It doesn't go off and find all the user groups that the user belongs to, so wouldn't work in an extended situation.  However, with application pools using the default identity, they should get either the app pool name or BUILTIN\Users

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$websites = (Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites)

foreach ($website in $websites)
{
    $appPool = (Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$($website.applicationPool))    
    Write-Output "Found $($website.name) with $($appPool.name) in mode $($appPool.processModel.identityType)";
    $folder = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($website.physicalPath);
    if ($appPool.processModel.identityType -eq 3)
    {
        $user = $appPool.processModel.userName;
        Write-Output "Using explicit username '$user'";
    } else {
        $user = "IIS AppPool\" + $appPool.name;
        Write-Output "Using application pool name '$user'";
    }

    $permission = (Get-Acl $Folder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match $User -or $_.IdentityReference -match "BUILTIN\\Users" } | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
    If ($permission){
        $permission | % {Write-Host "User $($_.IdentityReference) has '$($_.FileSystemRights)' rights on folder $folder"}
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$User Doesn't have any permission on $Folder"
    }
}
```

On my system this gives the following output

```
Found Default Web Site with DefaultAppPool in mode ApplicationPoolIdentity
Using application pool name 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool'
User BUILTIN\Users has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights on folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot
User BUILTIN\Users has '-1610612736' rights on folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Comment: My web service is under the `DefaultAppPool` just like the `Default Web Site` when we open IIS for the first time. I just noticed in the `Basic Settings...` when I click on `Test Settings...` I get this : `Cannot verify access to path ('C:\Path\To\API)`

Comment: Then the user will be IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool and that user need rights assigning on the directory C:\Path\To\Api using File Explorer.  If you are on a work domain, then you need to make sure you set the location to the local machine when attempting to add the user.  See the above link for more info.

Comment: I've made everything in your link, when i try to `connect as...` I get `The user name or password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)` and `The credentials used to access the specified physical path are invalid. Verify the credentials and test these settings again.`

Comment: I used `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` has user, no password. It's on the good pool, and full writes for `DefaultAppPool` user.

Comment: Use icacls to export the permissions and double check it’s correct. If you want, send me it privately and I’ll check over it.

Comment: I've double checked, every one is on `Full Control` (not recommended I guess). How do i share you my file if you want to check up?

Comment: I've update my answer with some powershell code to check permissions.  Probably best to run it elevated to make sure there are no rights issues when trying to run it.

Comment: `Found API with DefaultAppPool in mode ApplicationPoolIdentity
Using application pool name 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool'
User BUILTIN\Users has 'FullControl' rights on folder D:\DEV\API
User BUILTIN\Users has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights on folder D:\DEV\API
User BUILTIN\Users has '-1610612736' rights on folder D:\DEV\API
Found Default Web Site with DefaultAppPool in mode ApplicationPoolIdentity
Using application pool name 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool'
IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool Doesn't have any permission on C:\MyPath`
I updated permissions on `C:` and it works! Thank YOU!

Comment: I used Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)); and I am getting access to path is denied.  Do you think application pool is blocking the iuser.

Comment: If you want to check a specific directory, change the `$folder =` part to be the full path to the folder that you want to check.  The above script is checking the website root.

Answer (score 1):

Your WebAPI tries to access the path `C:\\Path\\To\\API`. It runs on behalf of IIS user that doesn't have access to it. Try to grant access to `NETWORK_SERVICE` user as well. Then perform `iisreset` from CMD just in case.

If this doesn't work, just move your project to disk `D:`, as disk `C:` is a system disk and it's typically more restrictive.

Comment: I tried `NETWORK_SERVICE`and moving the file to `D:`, did not work.